# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer() losing contraints

Tags: c#, smo, transfer

I'm trying to copy SQL database from one server to another.

Please tell me how to use Transfer() method without loosing constraints in the target database.

I've tried different parameters including

```
 CopySchema = true;     // and 
 CopyAllSchemas = true; //and even 
 CopyAllObjects = true;
```

and still this damn thing is losing all the constraints.

Help me, pls!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok...

```
 transfer.Options.DriAll = true;
```

helped. But now It's leaving all triggers behind

Comment: Your post really helped me. Did you find a way to copy triggers as well.

Comment: Oh My... it was pretty long time ago. I honestly don't remember. It might still leave the triggers behind if you're operating with SQL Express. But I'm not sure if that was an issue. Frankly I don't remember how I solved that... And I believe I don't have any source-code anymore

Comment: Set [Transfer.Options.Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.triggers.aspx) = true.

Answer (score 1):

In options some flags for select the object to copy

```
  transfer.Options.Triggers = true;
  transfer.Options.Indexes = true;
  transfer.Options.Statistics = true;
```